# Is there a way to verify if some CSS files are compiled from a certain LESS file?

Tags: css, compilation, compare, less

I have a variety of *CSS* files and some *LESS* files. The *CSS* files have different prefixes and suffixes that the *LESS* files don't, so I can't know with certainity if a *CSS* file is derivated from certain *LESS* file just for the names of the files.

I was wondering if there is a tool, plugin, extension, method, way or similar to check a *CSS* against a *LESS* file and determine if the *CSS* file was compiled from the *LESS* given file and, if possible, to what degree.

Comment: i can't understand , You want to know from any file less doing the compiler ?

Comment: @RamyRagab I'd like to know for a given CSS file it's most likely LESS source. My problem is CSS files are not equivalent to given LESS files because CSS files were edited directly and LESS files were ignored. I'd like to  integrate changes done to CSS files into their corresponding LESS files, but I don't know which LESS files compiled which CSS. I hope is more clear now...  Thanks for your interest.

Comment: Personally I see no other ways except compiling the corresponding Less files and then compare the result using a usual diff/compare tool (it may be tricky though to guess if there're some specific Less options and/or non-explicit imports etc.). The task is waaaay too specific/rare for someone to write a tool/script or something like this to automate.

Comment: @seven-phases-max Yup, I just was wondering if there was a magic trick somewhere out there that could help.